# Spark: What is the best way to do label encoding on a feature of variable length?

Tags: apache-spark, label-encoding

For Spark, there is a `StringIndexer` in Spark ML that can do label encoding for a given column. However it cannot directly handle the situation where the column is **variable length feature (or  multi-value feature)**. For example,

```
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  jobid|        country_list|     typeofwork_list|             publish|              expire|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|1636051|USA;Spain;China;A...|1441;1442;1443      |27/03/2017 2:00:0...|3/04/2017 1:59:59 PM|
|1636052|USA;Spain;Japan;A...|1441;1442           |27/03/2017 2:00:0...|3/04/2017 1:59:59 PM|
|1636053|UK;Spain;China;A....|1442;1443           |27/03/2017 2:00:0...|3/04/2017 1:59:59 PM|
|1636054|USA;Spain;China;A...|1443                |27/03/2017 2:00:0...|3/04/2017 1:59:59 PM|
```

The  `country_list` and `typeofwork_list` columns are variable length features. They can have more than a single value in one column, and the number of values is variant. When I wanna do label encoding on them, I cannot use `StringIndexer` directly on these columns.

Taking the `country_list` column for example, something like the following is the result I need:

```
+--------------------+
|        country_list|
+--------------------+
|0;1;2;3...          |
|0;1;4;3...          |
|5;1;2;3...          |
|0;1;2;3...          |
```

**What is the best way to do label encoding on such columns in Spark?**

One way I am thinking is first `explode` the `country_list` into a single-column dataframe, then do label encoding (`StringIndexer`) on this interim dataframe. After that, `dropDulicate`, then `collect` it, now I should have the mapping.　Then I can `broadcast` the mapping to all worker machines. The original Dataframe can use a `UDF` which wraps the mapping to transform the `country_list` column. I'm wondering is there easier ways to do this?

Thank you.